# How to get the Sudoku puzzle main contour

Tags: python, opencv

I have done the following:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def preprocessing_img(image, debug=False):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blurr = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (7,7), 3)
    img_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_blurr,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    img_thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(img_thresh)

    if debug:
        plt.imshow(img_thresh)
        plt.show()

    return img_thresh

def resize_img(image, img_size=DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE):
    return cv2.resize(image, img_size)

def get_puzzle_contour(contour):
    puzzle_contour = None
    for cnt in contour:
        periphery = cv2.arcLength(cnt, False)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * periphery, True)

        if len(cnt) == 4:
            puzzle_contour = approx
            return puzzle_contour

def find_contours(img_thresh):
    contours = cv2.findContours(img_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
    if len(contours) == 0:
        return
    else: 
        segmented_cnts = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
        return segmented_cnts


soduko_img = cv2.imread("soduko_imgs/1.png")
soduko_img = resize_img(soduko_img)

img_thresh = preprocessing_img(soduko_img, True)
segmented_cnts = find_contours(img_thresh)

soduko_contour = get_puzzle_contour(segmented_cnts)
if soduko_contour is None: 
    raise Exception(("Could not find soduko puzzle outline."))
```

[image]

The image shows the result, but it doesn't work like expected. I want to draw the contour of the whole soduko puzzle to transform and crop the image afterwards.
Can anybody help me? What I am doing wrong.

This is the original image I have used: [image]

Comment: For the others that struggle with the image: There is a small green dot on the very right. Also, where is `find_contours` defined?

Comment: I have updated the code. find_contours is now defined.

Comment: Please provide the input image so we can run and debug the code

Comment: I have provide the input image in the initial post. I hope you can help me. I tested my code also with other images and I got the same confusing result.